# Is it possible to access to a container from an iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, c++98

For this question, consider a simple example of a function adding values in a vector :

```
void insert( std::set<double>::const_iterator from_begin,
             std::set<double>::const_iterator from_end,
             std::vector<double>::iterator to )
{
  std::copy(from_begin, from_end, to);
}
```

Now immagine I want to add a check on the capacity of my vector, **is it possible to get the container on which `to` works ?** Is it possible to do something like that ?

```
void insert( std::set<double>::const_iterator from_begin,
             std::set<double>::const_iterator from_end,
             std::vector<double>::iterator to )
{
  std::vector<double>& container = give_me_the_container(to);
  assert(container.size() + std::distance(from_end,from_begin) < container.capacity());
  std::copy(from_begin, from_end, to);
}
```

**Note:** I use gcc 4.8.3. **I don't use c++11** for compatibility with old gcc versions.

Comment: Definitely not in a standard way, and I am not aware of any specific implementation extension or nasty hack. The `vector<double>::iterator` points only into the buffer, which has no link back to the owning object.

Comment: Since the `insert` function as written applies only to `vector<double>`, just change it to operate on the appropriate vectors.

Comment: @PeteBecker: as I said, it's a simplified example. I'm not looking for a workaround on this specific case.

Comment: @Caduchon - <shrug> the example you gave is the example you gave.

Comment: Okay, but my real case uses variant, shared pointer, threads, filtered iterators on something like 100 different kind of iterators. I'm sure it's not a good idea to provide this direclty... Howerver, my question was explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, nothing in the iterator's API can retrieve the container. As a matter of fact, a `T*` is a perfectly valid implementation of `std::vector<T>::iterator`.

On a side note, I'm not sure what you want to guard against in this snippet. Passing in `vec.end()` to your function, even if the capacity is sufficient, won't work, you need `std::back_inserter`.

Comment: Yeah, you're maybe right. Actually, my real problem is more complicated. I tried to create a simple dummy example, only exposing the problem. In my real problem, I have to pass the container when I print it with filtering iterators only to retrieve a global information. It's not elegant...

Comment: @Caduchon I'm not sure I see what you mean, but taking in the container itself wouldn't surprise me if the function actually needs it.

Comment: My container has filter iterators. When I print a filtered part of it, I have to call `print(data, data.begin_valid(), data.end_valid());` because I have to access to `data.pattern()`. I hoped it was possible to have a more elegant call : `print(data.begin_valid(), data.end_valid());` able to retrieve the pattern from the iterators. In my case, I can create an interface of the iterators able to store it, but it's more work than expected.

Comment: @Caduchon I'm afraid these are your only solutions.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible.

(as a hint, `std::vector<double>::iterator` might be `double*`).